# Is it worthwhile to attend Microsoft Dreamspark workshop for developing windows apps?

Tags: apps, store, microsoft-account

In the city where I live there will be a national summit on education next week, in which a Dreamspark workshop will be offered by Microsoft.
The program include a lesson about Wordpress on WebApp, an introduction to Cloud and MS Azure for Dreamspark and the **activation** of Azure for Dreamspark, including the **code** provided to all the students which will attend the course.

I never used or installed Dreamspark, in any case I read that the free activation of Dreamspark is already free for students, isn't it? Or may I get any other advantages in having the code provided at the workshop?

I also read on Microsoft website that these kind of workshops give the possibility to activate a developer account **for free** , whereas usually it requires a paid subscription, as far as I know (could you confirm that?).

So my question is:

- given the assumptions above, is it worthwile to attend a Dreamspark worhshop, with regard to the financial advantages and if my aim is developing windows apps?